# How to summarize a list of point-clouds

Tags: c#, list, union, point-clouds, any

I have a large list of a specific datatype called "Spot". Each element of the list contains a list of Points (Point => struct from Systems.Drawing) among other fields.

```
public class Spot
{
    public List<Point> PointCloud { get; set; }
    ...
}
List<Spot> spots = new List<Spot>();
```

I'd like to summarize the list spots in the following way:
If one element of spots contains at least one Point in its PointCloud which is equal to one Point of the PointCloud of another element, then they can be summarized/merged. That means that the PointClouds are united to one (easy with Union-Method) and one element can be removed from the list spots. I already got that:

```
while (spots[counterA].PointCloud.Any(p => spots[counterB].PointCloud.Contains(p)))
{
     spots[counterA].PointCloud.Union(spots[counterB].PointCloud);
     spots.Remove(spots[counterB]);
     ...
}
```

The problems is, that the PointCloud of one element gets larger. So after each union I have to check the whole list of remaining elements again from the start for equal Points.
I'm not sure how to set the loops and counters, that the performance isn't going to zero. Maybe there's also a way to to this without loops.
I hope someone can help me to find an efficient way to summarize the list.

Comment: How many spots and points are we talking about here. 100's 1000000's ?

Comment: Yeah about 100's spots and at start each spots has circa 50 points. Maybe it's easier to store the points in an 2D array or two 1D array, not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the points are exactly the same you can use a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) to store the points. This will help greatly with performance since HashSet.Contains is O(0) instead of O(n).

Also, your usage of `Union` is incorrect, this return a new list, and you are not assigning it to anything. It would be more efficient to add the points to the existing list instead. I'm not sure how you intend the loop to work since you do now show the whole code, I would probably use something like this:

```
public class Spot
{
    public HashSet<Point> PointCloud { get; }
    public bool Intersect(Spot other) => other.PointCloud.Any(p => PointCloud.Contains(p));

    public void Add(Spot other)
    {
        foreach (var p in other.PointCloud)
        {
            PointCloud.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
    public static IEnumerable<Spot> Merge(List<Spot> spots)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spots.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j <spots.Count; j++)
            {
                if (spots[i].Intersect(spots[j]))
                {
                    spots[i].Add(spots[j]);
                    // Remove the merged object, 
                    // and restart the loop,
                    // Since the merged set might intersect a previous spot
                    spots.RemoveAt(j);
                    j = i+1;
                }
            }

            yield return spots[i];
        }
       
    }
```

Note that if points are not *exactly* the same you cannot use HashSet to speedup the search. You would instead need to use something like a KD-tree or other search structure that allows for a reasonable fast way to find the closest point.

Also, the use of hashSet will only keep once instance of each point. So if two spots each have a point(1,1), the merged set will only have one such points and not two. Not sure if this is a problem or not.

Comment: Wow, that's actually exactly the solution I needed. To keep one instance of each point was also what I was looking for. That's why the Union-Method would also fit. But of course without an assignment, it's useless.
So thanks very much, JonasH! There's just one small mistake, I think.
`public bool Intersect(Spot other) => other.Any(p => PointCloud.Contains(p));`
doesn't work, it must be:
`public bool Intersect(Spot other) => other.PointCloud.Any(p => PointCloud.Contains(p));`
Then everything works fine!

Comment: @Till oups, fixed.